# Issue in loading embedded css and images for an unauthorized user access

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, angularjs, iis-10

I have angularjs application hosted within asp.net application which has web.config file. I am using ADFS for authentication and custom authorization implemented in this application.

The angularjs application has folder: assets which has all the static contents like css, js, img, fonts. There is also another folder errors which contains html pages for respective errors. auth.html is a page located within the errors folder.

At web.config file level I have the following setup :

```
<location path="errors/auth.html">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="assets/css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <!-- Add Caching Support for contents within folder: assets-->
    <system.webServer>
      <!--Caching-->
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="assets/fonts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <!-- Add Caching Support for contents within folder: assets-->
    <system.webServer>
      <!--Caching-->
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="assets/img">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <!-- Add Caching Support for contents within folder: assets-->
    <system.webServer>
      <!--Caching-->
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="assets/js">
    <!-- Add Caching Support for contents within folder: assets-->
    <system.webServer>
      <!--Caching-->
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

I have hosted the application in IIS with version :IIS Version: 10.0.17763.1 with folder name testapp created within the wwwroot folder.

Whenever any unauthorized user tries to open the application I need to display the auth.html page containing unauthorized message details.

On validating with unauthorized user I see html page rendered without css and images. Even though the auth.html has links to the css and images but they are not getting rendered.

auth.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Test Application</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/img/favicon.ico">
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/app.css">
  <!-- endinject -->
</head>

<header id="main-header" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top error-page-header" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="/assets/img/logo-test.svg" width="92">
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li>
          <a>Test Application</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="error-page">
    <h2> You are not authorized to access Test Application.</h2>    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Thread.CurrentPrincipal is IClaimsPrincipal)
        {
            if (!((IClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal).Identities[0].Claims.Exists(c => c.ClaimType == "TestApp_UserAuthorized") || !Convert.ToBoolean(((IClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal).Identities[0].Claims.Single(c => c.ClaimType == "TestApp_UserAuthorized").Value))
            {
                //Avoid Redirection for static files (used in Access denied page)
                List<string> staticcontentpaths = new List<string>{".css", ".js", ".png", ".gif", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".ico", ".svg", ".woff", ".ttf"};
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath).ToLower();
                if (!staticcontentpaths.Contains(extension))
                {
                    Server.Execute("~/errors/auth.html");
                    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue

Comment: Through my test, everything works normal. CSS and image can load successfully and response headers are well.https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt5s4.png  .So what is the status code of css and image in browser and what is message it display?

Comment: Thanks @BruceZhang for your response. On accessing the app.css explicitly via the browser I see it gets downloaded with HTTP STATUS CODE: 200.

Comment: The 200 status code indicates that the resource is loaded normally and should be displayed. Have you tried clearing the cache or switching browsers and requesting again?

Comment: Remove cache and reloaded it but no change in response. I still see the html page without css applied to it

Comment: Can you show the image of loading information of css files, static images and js files in the browser development mode?